# How to keep a flask submerged in water?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I am trying to keep a 1000 ml Erlenmeyer flask submerged in a deep cooking pot filled with water. I tried tying the flask to a metal plate, but it was too light unfortunately.

Is there a purpose built piece of equipment for this or a commonly accepted method?

Comment: Why you need the flask submerged - what you are trying to accomplish will determine the answer. Is the submerged flask corked or is it filled with the water in which it is submerged.? Will you be boiling the water?

Comment: Try something like these: https://www.thomassci.com/scientific-supplies/Weight-Rings. Any major lab supply company should have something similar.

Comment: What is stopping you clamping the neck of the flask in a fixed position using a simple lab clamp and stand?

Comment: @matt_black: Is it possible to move the stand base out of the way so I can put my electric hotplate there instead? I don't have a stand at the moment.

Comment: @Raghib Clamps and stands are versatile and are designed to enable you to clamp things where they need to be clamped. You can arrange them whatever way you need to.

Comment: @matt_black: Does this look good? https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Chemistry-Laboratory-Retort-Base-Stand-Support-Lab-Flask-Clamp-3-Ring-Clamp-Z0HW/293004454736?hash=item44386d2b50:g:c~8AAOSwCPZb7meC

Comment: Yes. Those are the standard stands/clamps widely used in every lab to hold things where you want them to be.

Answer (score 1):

The vinyl coated lead rings suggested in the comment are a great solution. They are, however, expensive and take time to order. There is also the cost of shipping.

A quick and less expensive route is to use a PVC flange and attach what ever heavy metal you have (steel, cast iron, lead fishing weights). Epoxy to flange or drill holes and tie. You may want to paint the metal to avoid rust or other reactions with the metal.

Home Depot has inexpensive [3" flange](https://www.homedepot.com/p/4-in-x-3-in-PVC-DWV-SPG-Closet-Flange-C48512HD43/100128450) or [4" flange](https://www.homedepot.com/p/4-in-x-4-in-PVC-DWV-Closet-Flange-C4851HD4/100345759).

Answer (score 1):

I would use a (coated) steel ring holder mounted to a heavy and secured rod holder.

Such a ring would be set to push and keep the Erlenmeyer flask down.

Such rings are commonly used in classing frame based settings to hold modular glass aparatures, e.g to support mesh plates with boiling flasks, or holding conical glass shapes.